# Gridview binding without using a Database

Tags: asp.net

Can a GridView be bound to a List<>?

I want to create a Master Details scenario. So The first List<> contains Master data and the second Child data. When the user clicks on the Master Data, the child data, should appear in a pop.

Is that possible? Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  Take a look at the [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx) to use for databinding a list to a GridView.  It requires some more manual coding, but it works.

There's a good discussion of one possible solution [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2006/05/11/144539.aspx) that manually constructs a DataTable from your business object list to make filtering/sorting/paging easier than manually implementing those methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.DataSource = theList;<br/>
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create on **temporary table** and then bind that table with grid.
Like,

> dataset.DataSource=tempTable;
>
> tempTable.DataBind();